# Wordpress create database not working

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to set up a database to use for displaying purposes in the `add_menu_page()`. **I'm using this on a custom parent theme**

Now I have this so far  (currently in my `functions.php`):

```
function countriesDB_init()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'designitcountries';

    //create table (if it doesnt exist)

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE" . " " . $table_name . "(
  id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
  name tinytext NOT NULL,
  text text NOT NULL,
  url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

        $name = 'Sukru Kintas';
        $title = 'President';
        $country = 'World all hapkido association';

        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'time' => current_time('mysql'),
                'title' => $title,
                'name' => $name,
                'country' => $country
            )
        );
}
do_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'countriesDB_init' );
```

It should create a database table when it does not exist yet. But it's not doing anything. No database table has been created.

**WP_DEBUG log**

```
WordPress database-fout: [Table 'ID203293_lacroix.wp_designitcountries' doesn't exist]
SELECT COUNT(word) AS occurrence, word FROM `wp_designitcountries` GROUP BY word ORDER BY occurrence DESC

WordPress database-fout: [Table 'ID203293_lacroix.wp_designitcountries' doesn't exist]
SELECT COUNT(word) AS occurrence, word FROM `wp_designitcountries` GROUP BY word ORDER BY occurrence DESC

WordPress database-fout: [Table 'ID203293_lacroix.wp_designitcountries' doesn't exist]
SELECT COUNT(word) AS occurrence, word FROM `wp_designitcountries` GROUP BY word ORDER BY occurrence DESC

WordPress database-fout: [Table 'ID203293_lacroix.wp_designitcountries' doesn't exist]
SELECT COUNT(word) AS occurrence, word FROM `wp_designitcountries` GROUP BY word ORDER BY occurrence DESC

WordPress database-fout: [Table 'ID203293_lacroix.wp_designitcountries' doesn't exist]
SELECT COUNT(word) AS occurrence, word FROM `wp_designitcountries` GROUP BY word ORDER BY occurrence DESC

WordPress database-fout: [Table 'ID203293_lacroix.wp_designitcountries' doesn't exist]
SELECT COUNT(word) AS occurrence, word FROM `wp_designitcountries` GROUP BY word ORDER BY occurrence DESC
```

Comment: your code is hard to understand. what does the function `dbDelta`? please show us error messages (set WP_DEBUG to true in the wp-config.php)

Comment: dbDelta is a function within Wordpress itself : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/

Comment: log is just saying that the table does not exist. Like i said its not being registred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbDelta()` is very picky, below I've checked the [requirements](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table) for `dbDelta()` in your code. As you can see below your code fails two of the requirements which most likely prevents `dbDelta()` from creating the tables.

- You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement. **CHECK**
- You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key. **CHECK**
- You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY. **N/A**
- KEY must be followed by a SINGLE SPACE then the key name then a space then open parenthesis with the field name then a closed parenthesis. **N/A**
- You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names. **CHECK**
- *Field types must be all lowercase.* **FAIL**
- SQL keywords, like CREATE TABLE and UPDATE, must be uppercase. **CHECK**
- *You must specify the length of all fields that accept a length parameter. int(11), for example.* **FAIL**

### Also

From the documentation:

> The dbDelta function examines the current table structure, compares it
>   to the desired table structure, and either adds or modifies the table
>   as necessary

Therefor your initial check `if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {` is redundant as `dbDelta()` does that for you.

Comment: I updated my code with what you said . Thanks for all the info. Seems that i overlooked some things. But its still not adding a database. I do switch my theme to another and back since the action hook says that

Comment: So also i can not use the hook that i putted on there , changing it to add_action ('init' , 'countriesDB'); got it also to work.  But i have your post as an answer because most people will have that problem